# Trying to use spanish characters (or ignoring them) on xml filenames with python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I did a code that change some xml filenames with the data on them by using regex and glob for opening my files and now everything works good but i tried a few things i found on web as encoding(), using some # -*- coding: (name) -*- at the start of my program but i can't make it use or ignore characters as "á" "é"

this is what i have on the top of my file:

```
#! python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import os, re, glob
from os import rename
```

the regex of the name stored on "emisor"

```
regexNombre = re.compile(r'(\sNombre\=\")(.+?)(\")')
```

from there i just store the second group

and finally the code where i change the name of the file, only having problems with "emisor" var

```
newname = (año + mes + dia + " " + emisor + " " + total + ".xml")
copiedText.close()
rename(filename, newname)
```

i noticed that i can use spanish characters on strings and can see them right when the program is executed, but in filenames it changes for another characters

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: Using windows 8